# Difference between "xvar=x1" and "xvar = ~x1" in wp() from gamlss package in R

Tags: r

I'm using the gamlss package in R to implement wormplots for the residuals study.
The function wp() has an argument xvar which is used for bucketing.

Assume I have a "numeric" vector x1 which if passed as "xvar = x1" behaves differently than "xvar = ~x1". Basically the second case is treated as a formula. The buckets created for both cases will be different from each other.

Code :-

```
library(gamlss)
glc<-gamlss.control(n.cyc = 200)
myseed <- 12345
set.seed(myseed) #this will make results reproducible
# generate data
N<-10000 # this is the sample size 
dd<-data.frame(x1=rpois(N,1)
              ,x2=rnorm(N,.7,.3)
              ,x3=log(rgamma(N,shape=6,scale=10))
              ,x4=sample(letters[1:3], N, replace = T)
              ,x5=sample(letters[3:6], N, replace = T)
              ,ind = rbinom(N,size=1,prob=0.5)
)

#Generate distributions
dd$y_wei1<-rweibull(N,scale=exp(.3*dd$x1+.8*dd$x3),shape=5)

m1 <- gamlss(formula = y_wei1 ~ x1 + x3 + x4 + x5,
                      data = dd ,
                      family = "WEI" ,
                      K = 2, 
                      control = glc
                     )

# Case 1.
wp(object = m1, xvar = x1, n.iter = 4)
# Case 2.
wp(object = m1, xvar = ~x1, n.iter = 4)
```

[image: Case 1 output]
[image: Case 2 output]

Edit :

I do observed that this happens only when the overlap argument is set to 0. Because when overlap=0 then internally another function( check.overlap) is called. Why is this function called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function has been written such that `xvar = ~x1` indicated `x1` is a factor/char variable and so grouping occurs based on its unique values. When user calls with `xvar = x1` then bins are created based on the range and that is used to generate the wormplots.

The difference is because internally there is a `check.overlap` fucntion written which is impemented only if `x1` is numeric. Incase of overlapping, it clips it to have non-overlapping intervals. This is missing if user calls it as `xvar = ~x1`.